# How to know when a server updates my HashMap in java

Tags: java, wait

I have a client end (say Customer) that sends request (with RequestID 1) to server end and receives ack for the sent request. My server end (say SomeStore) processes the request 1 and sends to Customer and receives ack (or resends three times). I have another thread listening at Customer. Upon receiving the Customer's listener thread should update HashMap at key 1. All I need is to wait and retrieve this updated value at key 1.

I have a thread from a threadpool to send request and recieve ack on both ends. I see that both threads do the process of sending. I also have a threadpool for listener. After receiving ack, if I make my main thread wait in a while loop, I don't see the listener's update. (Here I cannot make it with wait()). I don't understand this behavior. Shouldn't both threads be working?

I tried changing my implementation and created a separate class upon receiving and synchroned with this.wait() on myHashMap.get(key) and this.notify() on myHashMap.set(key, value). It works a couple of times and not always. My understanding is that it depends on which thread gets the lock first.

How else do I wait and listen at the same time? Maybe I am overseeing something obvious...
It is easy to receive reply instead of ack but my request gets lost in the network. Therefore using ack. I am already using Callable<> for ack. Any idea is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are not using thread safe access to the map.

If it's not a ConcurrentHashMap and you are not using synchronization, there is no guarentee you will ever see a change in a HashMap.

Instead of using wait/notify and your own threads, I suggest you use ConcurrentHashMap and [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) and add tasks to perform the update.  This will ensure you process and see every update.

Comment: I am already using ExecutorService's ThreadPool to listen and to update. I tried both Collections.synchronizedMap and ConcurrentHashMap. myHashMap is static. When I use this.wait(500), I see that myHashMap is updated. But when I stop waiting and retrieve, it is null. Why would a static map not be visible for a thread after update?

Comment: Are you updating the map before triggering the other thread to read it?

Comment: It is updated only while the reading thread is waiting and not before. I am accessing only after update, but update is not visible to the accessing process. Shouldn't a static map be visible? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The Map itself should always be visible no matter what you do.  The changes to the map will always be visible if the writes and reads are performed correctly.

Comment: In the update method I use result.put(key, value); and print immediately using result.get(key). I see the updated value. I use the same result.get(key) to retrieve after update, I get a nullPointerException. So I don't see why.

Comment: I walked around it by using a map on the server end, and retrieved info more or less like polling. @Peter Lawrey I am still trying to understand thread behavior, I appreciate that you answered.  Thanks!

Comment: If your map is a `static final` variable, as it should be if it is `static`, it's not clear to me how you can see it as a `null` value in one thread but not another.